# android http POST send two parameters including bitmap

Tags: android, http, post

I was sending `String` via POST:

```
            connection = new URL(UrlAddress).openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
            //urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            String charset = "UTF-8";  
            String param1 = "test";

            String query = String.format("param1=%s",
                    URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset));
            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));

            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Can I send two parameters via one POST operation, like `String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", ...`? I need to append bytes sequence parameter (bitmap picture) to POST after text type parameter, how should I write it?

Comment: You want to send GET and POST method same time ?

Comment: Yes you can. And you tried of course. But do not url encode if you POST.

Comment: ' connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.'. No. For POST you have to set the method.